# JSON.parse: expected double-quoted property name (var json = JSON.parse( xhr.responseText );)

Tags: json, three.js

https://www.dropbox.com/s/h59v7elqn05t7lc/bag.js

the following code gives the link to the json file is given

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected double-quoted property name
```

**Javascript:**

```
var init = function () {
    var canv = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
    var w = canv.clientWidth;
    var h = canv.clientHeight;

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        canvas: canv
    });
    renderer.setSize(w, h);

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        15, // Field of view
    w / h, // Aspect ratio
    0.1, // Near
    10000 // Far
    );
    camera.position.set(-1, 1, 15);
    scene.add(camera);

    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFDD);
    light.position.set(-15, 10, 15);
    scene.add(light);

    var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x999999);
    scene.add(ambient);

    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    var onGeometry = function (geom) {
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial());
        scene.add(mesh);
    };
    loader.load("vwbug.js", onGeometry);

    var render = function () {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    setInterval(render, 10);
};

window.onload = init;
window.onresize = init;
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think this is caused by extra comma at line 8.

```
"materials": [ { 
    "DbgColor" : 15658734, 
    "DbgIndex" : 0, 
    "DbgName" : "dummy", 
    "colorDiffuse" : [ 1, 0, 0 ], 
} ],
```

To spot issues like that validators may help, for example, http://jsonlint.com.

Comment: Line 22 also has an extra comma.

Comment: ok fixed it but its saying .. TypeError: material is undefined... but the materials are defined :\

Comment: "ok fixed it but its saying .. TypeError: material is undefined... but the materials are define" - for this issue you may want to create separate question for others to comment (unless you can debug it on your end). This seems to be three.js related, and I am not that good at it. :)

Answer (score -1):

This function worked very well for me:

```
function fixJsonString(str) {
 const fixedStr = str.replace(/'/g, '"').replace(/(\w+):/g, '"$1":');
 return JSON.parse(fixedStr);
}
```

The specific case is when one of the properties of the object does not come double-quoted (") so the parser finds it conflictive.

This simplistic function got me busy for 2 days, so I truly hope anyone would find it useful.